# Remove labels and tics from subplots

Tags: python, plot

I tried following what suggested in other posts but it doesn't work (example pic below).

I need to plot, in the same image, a set of frames and I would like to remove, for each subplot, both tics and labels. Do you spot any error in my code (below)? Let mw know if you would use another approach!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Figure which will include the other frames
fig, axes = plt.subplots(A.shape[0], A.shape[0], figsize=(15,15))

# Iteratively add the frames
for i in range(A.shape[0]*A.shape[0]):
    a1 = fig.add_subplot(A.shape[0],A.shape[0],i+1)
    aa = Data_angle[i,0]
    bb = Data_angle[i,1]
    plt.imshow(A[int(aa),int(bb),omega,:,:])

    labels = [item.get_text() for item in a1.get_xticklabels()]
    empty_string_labels = ['']*len(labels)
    a1.set_xticklabels(empty_string_labels)

    labels = [item.get_text() for item in a1.get_yticklabels()]
    empty_string_labels = ['']*len(labels)
    a1.set_yticklabels(empty_string_labels)

    a1.set(xticks=[], yticks=[])

fig.text(0.5, 0.04, 'Gamma', ha='center')
fig.text(0.04, 0.5, 'Mu', va='center', rotation='vertical')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `axis('off')` to hide the axis completely.
Doing this, you have to add into your foor loop this line

```
a1.axis('off')
```

This will hide the entire axis, so that there are no labels or ticks anymore visible.